# Efficiently drawing text using Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, performance, raphael

I'm drawing a chart using Raphael.js and am running into a performance issue concerning text.  I'm currently using the following pattern to draw text:

```
var labels = paper.set();    

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
  labels.push(paper.text(0, i * 10, 'my text'));
}

labels.attr({'font-size',10});
```

However, using this method seems to be very slow.  I can draw 400 rectangles (using a single path string) twice as fast as I can add 6 labels to the chart.  Is there any way to batch up text drawing or a different way to do this that is faster?  At the moment, almost 80% of my drawing time is spent adding labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in your example, I've tested the following using `console.time()`. It appears that your `push` adds about 10% to the time, where as your `attr` call almost doubles the process. For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4200; i++ ) {
  labels.push(paper.text(0, i * 10, 'my text'));
}
```

Resulted in:

```
labels: 3452ms
attr: 2455ms
```

Where as, when we removed the attr calls:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4200; i++ ) {
  paper.text(0, i * 10, 'my text');
}
```

Resulted in:

```
labels: 3011ms
attr: 0ms
```

Doing this by chaining has little effect on performance.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4200; i++ ) {
  labels.push(paper.text(0, i * 10, 'my text').attr({'font-size':10}));
}
```

Resulted in:

```
draw: 5759ms
```

Next we analyzed the amount of characters in a string to determine if there is any direct correlation between number of characters drawn, and time elapsed.

`paper.text(5, i * 10, '0');` resulted in a time of `draw: 2974ms`

`paper.text(5, i * 10, 'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext');` resulted in a time of `draw: 3122ms` which is negligable.

Now lets try that case you spoke of, with the rectangles. Lets draw the same amount, using the same positioning, and only change a few attributes that will not affect render times (width and height)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4200; i++ ) {
  paper.rect(5, i * 10, 50, 50);
}
```

Resulted in:

```
draw: 333ms
```

As the numbers show, I believe this is because we are drawing vectors with incredibly more complex curves. A squares vector formula is going to be exponentially shorter, and easier to calculate then a series of letters and their curves.

Comment: I'm not sure that this actually answers my question, but I appreciate the analysis.  My main question was that with rects, you can create a single path string to generate hundreds of rectangles but as far as I know, there is no similar method for text in Raphael.js - text has to be immediately added to the paper.  I've since switched to using d3.js and the same test that takes me 6872 ms in Raphael.js (4200 text blocks with font size) takes 2351 ms.

Comment: I'm sorry I seemed to not have concluded my post! There is no way (short of importing paths of text if commonly used words exist) to do what you're asking. Raphael is not as robust or powerful as some of the other libraries out there, but is very reliable and easy to use. When it comes to optimization, I find using vanilla javascript is your best bet. Explore the text methods of both libraries to see where the issues are, and maybe you can write a better implementation then they have.

An example of your "path string" woulda been really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any use, but I've found it fairly quick to use normal divs for text labels (rather than vectors.)